# Restart a running process if it outputs a particular string?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

I want to loop  a process in a bash script, it is a process which should run forever but which sometimes fails.

When it fails, it outputs `>>747;3R` to its last line, but keeps running.

I tried (just for testing)

```
while [ 1 ]
do
  mono Program.exe
  last_pid=$1
  sleep 3000
  kill $last_pid
done
```

but it doesn't work at all, the process `mono Program.exe` just runs forever (until it crashes, but even then my script does nothing.)

Comment: Could you try `while true; do mono Program.exe & last_pid=$!; sleep 3000; kill $last_pid; done`?

Comment: [Crosspost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40481879/restart-program-if-it-outputs-some-string)